# Is it possible to merge Azure Data Factory data flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have two separate Data flows in Azure Data Factory, and I want to combine them into a single Data flow.

There is a technique for copying elements from one Data flow to another, as described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_1I4XdoBKQ

This does not work for Source or Sink stages, though. The Script elements do not contain the Dataset that the Source or Sink is connected to, and if you try to copy them, the designer window closes and the Data flow is corrupted. The details are in the JSON, but I have tried copying and pasting into the JSON and that doesn't work either - the source appears on the canvas, but is not usable.

Does anyone know if there is a technique for doing this, other than just manually recreating the objects on the canvas?

Comment: I‘m afraid no,  there isn't a technique for doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Leon for confirming that this isn't supported, here is my workaround process.

1. Open the Data Flow that will receive the merged code.
2. Open the Data Flow that contains the code to merge in.
3. Go through the to-be-merged flow and change the names of any transformations that clash with the names of transformations in the target flow.
4. Manually create, in the target flow, any Sources that did not already exist.
5. Copy the entire script out of the to-be-merged flow into a text editor.
6. Remove the Sources and Sinks.
7. Copy the remaining transformations into the clipboard, and paste them in to the target flow's script editor.
8. Manually create the Sinks, remembering to set all properties such as "Allow Update".

Be prepared that, if you make a mistake and paste in something that is not correct, then the flow editor window will close and the flow will be unusable. The only way to recover it is to refresh and discard all changes since you last published, so don't do this if you have other unpublished changes that you don't want to lose!

I have already established a practice in our team that no mappings are done in Sinks. All mappings are done in Derived Column transformations, and any column name ambiguity is resolved in a Select transformations, so the Sink is always just auto-map. That makes operations like this simpler.

It should be possible to keep the Source definitions in Step 6, remove the Source elements from the target script, and paste the new Sources in to replace them, but that's a little more complex and error-prone.